# Verilog Syntax Error

Tags: verilog

It's verilog code and can't simulate because of syntax error. Anyone know how to solve it?

```
assign x = (Status == 2'b00)?
{Board[0],1'b0,1'b0,Board[2],1'b0,1'b0,Board[1],1'b0,Board[3],1'b0,1'b0,Board[5],1'b0,1'b0,Board[4],1'b0,1'b0,Board[6],1'b0,1'b0,Board[8],1'b0,1'b0,Board[7],1'b0,Board[9],1'b0,1'b0,Board[11],1'b0,1'b0,Board[10],1'b0,Board[12],1'b0,1'b0,Board[14],1'b0,1'b0,Board[13],1'b0,Board[15],1'b0,1'b0,Board[17],1'b0,1'b0,Board[16],1'b0}:

(Status == 2'b01)?
64'b0110000001100000011000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000: 

(Status == 2'b10)?
64'b1101101011011010110110101101101000000000000000000000000000000000:

(Status == 2'b11)?
64'b1001110011101111011100100100000100000000000000000000000000000000:
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell regarding the location? If you can't understand what specifically it doesn't like from the message, start commenting out intergral parts of the code to pinpoint the offending construct.

Comment: Please,Can you share the error report?

Answer (score 2):

Form minimum code change:

```
//(Status == 2'b11)?// <- comment out for final condition
64'b1001110011101111011100100100000100000000000000000000000000000000 ; // <- semicolon, not colon
```

Better yet convert to a case statement. Easier to read and debug.

```
reg [63:0] x;
always @* begin
  case(Status)
  2'b00: x = ... ;
  2'b01: x = ... ;
  2'b10: x = ... ;
  2'b11: x = ... ;
  endcase
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x= (condition==2'b00)? a:(condition==2'b01)?:b:(condtion==2'b10)?:c:(condtion==2'b11)?:d
```

This is how your code looks when the values for assigning to x are replaced with a,b,c,d.The statement will definitely throw an error as you have clearly violated the way ternary operator is supposed to be used.

**Ternary operator syntax:**

```
x=(condition)?a:b
```

If the condition is true, x will be assigned the value of a.
If the condition is false, x will be assigned the value of b.

**Ternary operator syntax if used in a nested way:**

```
x=(condition1)?a:((condition2)?b:c)
```

If the condition1 is true, x will be assigned the value of a.
If the condition1 is false, it will check for condition2. If condition2 is true, x will be assigned the value of b else x will be assigned the value of c.

Looking at your code, you have repeated colons at inappropriate places.

```
x= (condition==2'b00)? a:(condition==2'b01)?:b:(condition==2'b10)?:c:(condition==2'b11)?:d
                                            ^                     ^
```

There should not be a colon after the question mark.
Probably you can rewrite the condition as:

```
assign x= (condition==2'b00)?a:(condition==2'b01)? b:(condition==2'b10)?c:d;
```

Look at the small verilog code that helps in understanding the working of nested ternary operator:
[Verilog code](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/TGM)

Hope my code helps you!

Answer (score -1):

You havent posted any specific error message.
A good way of Debugging :
**Use $Display("any text")** near line numbers that are pointed out as errors in the code by the compiler. From the code it seems you are doing a lot of Vector part Select. Case statement is a better choice.